# Django queryset model apply function in field

Tags: python, django, django-models

It is possible simulate this query SQL in Django models using function in field in where clause.

My Query SQL

```
SELECT id, name, email
  FROM students where md5(cast(id as text)) = 'e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5';
```

My Django model.

```
class Students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models
```

Methods in Django - Value of `where_filter` is a MD5 of value field `id`/`pk`.

```
where_filter = 'e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5'

Students.objects.get(pk=where_filter)
Students.objects.filter(pk=where_filter)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a custom [Transform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-lookups/#a-simple-transformer-example) class.

Something like:

```
class Md5Value(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'md5'
    output_field = CharField()

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connectino):
        lhs, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        return "MD5(cast(%s as text))"  % lhs, params

AutoField.register_lookup(MD5Value)
```

Now you can do:

```
where_filter = 'e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5'

Students.objects.get(pk__md5=where_filter)
```

Comment: looks like a typo in code example - AutoField.register_lookup(MD5Value), 'D' in parameter 'MD5Value' needs to be in lowercase
and 'connectino' -> 'connection'